# My Angular 5 Pipe "trim" is not getting called, why?

Tags: angular, pipe, angular-pipe

I've created an angular `Pipe` named `trim`. This pipe is designed to remove the last character from the string. Here is my pipe class `TrimPipe`. The console is not logging the values when the pipe is used inside the HTML.
HTML usage here -

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let bg of backgrounds.preferred">
       <span>{{bg.name ? (bg.name + ', ') : '' | trim}}</span>
   </ng-container>
```

---

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'trim'
})
export class TrimPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    console.log(value, args, 'Pipes');
    return value.toString().substring(0, value.length - 1);
  }

}
```

My `app.module.ts` file -

```js
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

// Custom
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {CommonService} from './shared/services/common.service';
import {DirectivesModule} from './shared/directives/directives.module';
import {PipeModule} from './shared/pipe/pipe.module';]


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    DirectivesModule,
    PipeModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [CommonService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

My `pipe.module.ts` -

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TrimPipe } from './trim.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [TrimPipe],
  exports: [TrimPipe]
})
export class PipeModule { }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only using the pipe on an empty string when bg.name is falsy. Fix by moving parentheses:

```
<span>{{(bg.name ? bg.name + ', ' : '') | trim}}</span>
```

By the way, you'd gain performance benefits if you moved the entire logic to a pipe or pre-formatted the string before passing it to a template (ie. in component or service code). Angular runs all evaluations in template interpolations on every change detection cycle, while pure pipes are cached until the input value changes.

Comment: Now I can sleep in peace.... Thanks a lot man... such a silly mistake..

Answer (score -1):

Here's a really conservative version of that, which should catch any errors.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'trim'})
export class TrimPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(inValue: any): string {
    let value = '';
    try {
      value = inValue.toString();
      console.log('TrimPipe: >>' + value + '<<');
      return value.substring(0, value.length - 1);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

Overall your code looks like it's going to the right place but there're a couple of issues I see:

1. The transform should always be returning a string
2. It can be a good idea to try/catch around the innards, so you have a chance to see any errors.

I find for lower-level things that are going to be used in random places that it's a good idea to write them "defensively" to survive anything that can be thrown at them.

Comment: Javascript engines will let you know of any uncaught errors u know :)

Comment: Yeah, I've had situations where they show up in unexpected places and it can be hard to track them through thirty-five layers of closures, so I tend to try and catch them as close to where they happen, if I feel it's appropriate.